# Assign a user to AspNetUserRole in Console Line Application C#

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-identity, console-application, asp.net-roles

I have a program where I read a CSV file of email addresses and user data, and bring it into a C# console line application, and write each one into the AspNetUser table (assuming it passes validation).

I can write in a new user via the following code:-

```
AspNetUser user = new AspNetUser();
user.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
user.UserName = username;
// More Code
db.AspNetUsers.Add(user);
db.SaveChanges();
```

How can I from here, assign them to a role, so adding a record in the AspNetUsersRole table? The table is not accessible through LINQ? I don't seem to have access to UserManager or ApplicationUser in the console line application?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using Identity, you should use the `UserManager` and `RoleManager` classes to manage your users/roles.

Comment: How can I access these from a console application though? Intellisense just offers me to create a new class of the same name? Is it a reference I need to add?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Identity, you should use the `UserManager` and `RoleManager` classes to manage your users/roles:

```
var user = new AspNetUser
{ 
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    UserName = username
};

var userManager = new UserManager<AspNetUser>();
userManager.Create(user, "password");
userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "RoleName");
```

But if you really want to stick with your context, then you can use the navigation property of the user:

```
var user = new AspNetUser
{ 
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    UserName = username
};

db.AspNetUsers.Add(user);
var role = db.AspNetRoles.Single(r => r.Name = "RoleName");
user.Roles.Add(role);
db.SaveChanges();
```